# Gnome pannel app error messages

Tags: pygtk, panel, gnome

How can I see what the problem is with a panel app in gnome, where are the errors logged to?

I am playing about with a panel app, in pygtk.  I can re-parent it and it works, but when I try to add it to the panel it fails, and I don't know why and cant see any errors.

Here is the code I use to separate real use from testing.

```
if DEBUG == True:
    from tempus_fugit import app
    main_window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    main_window.set_title("DEBUG:  Tempus Fugit Applet")
    main_window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    applet = gnomeapplet.Applet()
    app.tempus_fugit_factory(applet, None)
    applet.reparent(main_window)
    main_window.show_all()
    gtk.main()
else:
    from tempus_fugit import app
    gnomeapplet.bonobo_factory("OAFIID:TempusFugit_Factory", gnomeapplet.Applet.__gtype__, "Tempus Fugit", "0.1", app.tempus_fugit_factory)
```

So when debug is false, and it's launched via the panel "add to panel" feature how can I see the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and leave running:

```
$ tail -f ~/.xsession-errors
```

Later add your applet into the panel.  The messages will appear in your terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that works well.  A note for Ubuntu (and I imagine other debian derivatives) the file is called .xsession-errors on ubuntu.

Comment: It was a typo. You are right, it is .xsession-errors.  I just fixed it.